# Trouble removing an item using filter method from the flatList in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am having trouble removing an item from my flatlist in react native.  I am using the filter method to filter out the list that doesn't have the ID entered by the user to delete, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. When I click on the delete button the list isn't updated.

This is what I have so far:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, Button, Alert, Modal, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

const musiciansArray = [
  { id: 1, key: 'A', value: 'Pink Floyd', members: 4, songs: 165, albums: 13 },
  { id: 2, key: 'B', value: 'Deep Purple', members: 5, songs: 70, albums: 7 },
  { id: 3, key: 'C', value: 'AC/DC', members: 5, songs: 80, albums: 12 },
  { id: 4, key: 'D', value: 'The Doors', members: 4, songs: 100, albums:11 },
  { id: 5, key: 'E', value: 'Led Zeppelin', members: 4, songs: 95, albums: 5 },
  { id: 6, key: 'F', value: 'Tame Impala', members: 5, songs: 25, albums:4 },
  { id: 7, key: 'G', value: 'RHCP', members: 4, songs: 55, albums: 6 },
];

const App = () => {
  const [listItems, setListItems] = useState(musiciansArray);

  const [idDeleteInput, setIdDeleteInput] = useState();

  const [exampleArray, setExampleArray] = useState(musiciansArray);

  useEffect(() => {
    setListItems(exampleArray);
  }, [exampleArray]);


  const alertAdd = () => {
    var newArray = [...exampleArray, { id: exampleArray.length + 1, key: keyInput, value: itemInput, members: memInput, songs: songInput, albums: albumInput }];
    setExampleArray(newArray);
  };

  const delItem = (idDeleteInput) => {
    const filteredArray = exampleArray.filter(item => item.id !== idDeleteInput);
    setExampleArray(filteredArray);
  }
 
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.text1}>Bands</Text>
          <FlatList
            data={listItems}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorView}
            renderItem={ItemView}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}/>
        </View>
       
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.text3}>Delete</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text4}>Id to delete:</Text>
          <UselessTextInput
            multiline
            numberOfLines={4}
            value={idDeleteInput}
            onChangeText={delID => setIdDeleteInput(delID)}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.fixToText2}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={delItem}
            style={styles.button3}>
            <Text style={styles.textButton}>Press To Del</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You've written it assuming a click/press event would be passed as the id of the element to delete.

```
const delItem = (idDeleteInput) => { // <-- event object!
  const filteredArray = exampleArray.filter(item => item.id !== idDeleteInput);
  setExampleArray(filteredArray);
}

...

<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={delItem}
  style={styles.button3}
>
  <Text style={styles.textButton}>Press To Del</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

When you actually store in state the id you want to remove.

```
<Text style={styles.text4}>Id to delete:</Text>
<UselessTextInput
  multiline
  numberOfLines={4}
  value={idDeleteInput}
  onChangeText={delID => setIdDeleteInput(delID)}
/>
```

## Solution

Use the id from state to do the filtering.

```
const delItem = () => {
  const filteredArray = exampleArray.filter(item => item.id !== idDeleteInput);
  setExampleArray(filteredArray);
}
```

Comment: Hi, that still doesnt seem to work for me. I still see my original list, even though i have entered an ID which is to be deleted.

Comment: Hi, nevermind, i just altered my comparison operators, and it seems to work now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @coder101 I found the issue is a type comparison issue. `item.id` is a number, but `idDeleteInput` is a string. You can save it as a number as such: `onChangeText={(delID) => setIdDeleteInput(Number(delID))}`. [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/trouble-removing-an-item-using-filter-method-from-the-flatlist-in-react-native)